# on click - give a class to all the other li item except current one - grid

Tags: jquery, grid, click, overlay, addclass

I have this grid as you can see:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxBmYa

What i'm trying to do is just on click of one of the list, the image should keep the same, but all the other one should get some black opacity overlay ( same effect as hover).

For that I suppose I need to give a class to all the list item except the current one when i have click on one. and If i click to another one, to remove it to the new one and add it to the previous one.

Is this the current path ?

So far I've add this jquery which add a class to all the div, including the current one so this is not good  . . and my overlay doesn't appear but stay behind the image ( which is a background-image)

```
<script>


    $('ul.thumbs li').on('click', function(){

   $('ul.thumbs li').not(this).addClass('editable');

   });
</script>
```

Any idea to make this work . . would be incredible !

Thank you guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to me the black opacity overlay is coming from description span so instead of adding editable class make description span opacity to 1 as below

```
$('ul.thumbs li').on('click', function(){
   $('ul.thumbs li').find('.description').css('opacity',0);
   $('ul.thumbs li').not(this).find('.description').css('opacity',1);

});
```

Comment: hmmm, getting thereyes i have mistake the class, 

The problem is that now if i click to another list item, the state stay the same . . .   ( the new keep the opacity to 1 and the previous one to 0) :/ Do you have any idea about ?

thank you for your help !

Comment: you' re s star, thank you :)

Any chance to have the  text disappear on the other list item when click ? :) THank you :)

Comment: use something like $('ul.thumbs li').find('.description').css('opacity',0).html(''); it will remove content of span

Comment: Im going to be a pain, but is it possible to have the tet appear in hover only ? because now it doenst appear anymore in hover once i have click to  a list item :(

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I know it is been answered before but here is the example with boostrap grid:

https://jsfiddle.net/herculez/157kwx3t/

```
$(function() {
  $('.panel').click(function() { // when a .panel is clicked
    $('.panel').not(this).removeClass('active')
    $(this).toggleClass('active')
  })
})
```